# flutter how can i set button border like this

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need this button with same border
[image]

Here, this is my button code for this. But it's not looking like upper image.

```
ElevatedButton(

  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    shadowColor: Colors.black,
      elevation: 4.0,
    primary:Color(0xFF6200D4),
    onPrimary: Colors.white,
    // shadowColor: Colors.grey,
    // elevation: 8,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    side: BorderSide(
      color:  Color(0xFFFF7300),
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      width: 2.0,
    ),
    minimumSize: Size(300, 50), //////// HERE
  ),
  child:  Text('Login with Username',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UsernameLogin(title: 'Username Login Screen')));

  },
),
```

but my button look like different it's look little different from bottom side.

[image]

Comment: which image you want above or below?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q0ut.png    -> i need like this

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil  -> above  image -https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q0ut.png

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question, beware the colors and the height/width of the button are not correct.

```
 Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.orange],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
          height: 75,
          width: 300,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              shadowColor: Colors.black,
              elevation: 4.0,
              primary: const Color(0xFF6200D4),
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              // shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              // elevation: 8,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),

              minimumSize: const Size(300, 50), //////// HERE
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Login with Username',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UsernameLogin(title: 'Username Login Screen')));

            },
           ),
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have tried using [**`OutlinedButton`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html) button

```
 OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
              primary: Colors.white,
              side: BorderSide(
                width: 3.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Login With Username',
            ),
          ),
```

Result-> [image]